# Cocos2d removeChild not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        buttonPressed = NO;

        CCMenuItem *myMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon-72.png" selectedImage:@"Icon-Small.png"target:self selector:@selector(menuSelector:)];
        CCMenu *myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:myMenuItem, nil];
        myMenu.position = ccp(50, 50);
        // add the label as a child to this Layer
        [self addChild: myMenu];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)menuSelector:(id)sender{
    CCSprite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
    mySprite.position = ccp(100, 100);
    if (!buttonPressed) {
        buttonPressed = YES;
        [self addChild:mySprite];

    }
    else{
        [self removeChild:mySprite cleanup:YES];
        buttonPressed = NO;
    }

}
```

Why is removeChild:mySprite not working? mySprite still there after i pressed the button(myMenuItem) the second time. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you touch the button you're creating a new instance of the sprite.  You're probably better off creating and adding it as a class variable so you can access it in all methods, then just setting it's visibility on or off as needed.